# How to get PostgreSQL ROW values with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, row

I have this query:

```
SELECT  a.apartment_id, a.building_id, a.apartment_num, a.floor, at.app_type_desc_en AS app_type_desc,
    (SELECT ROW(e.e_name, ot.otype_desc_en)
    FROM    TABLE_TENANTS t INNER JOIN TABLE_OWNERSHIP_TYPES ot ON ot.otype_id=t.ownership_type INNER JOIN TABLE_ENTITIES e ON
t.entity_id = e.entity_id
WHERE   a.apartment_id = t.apartment_id AND t.building_id = a.building_id
ORDER BY t.ownership_type DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS t_row
    FROM    TABLE_APARTMENTS a INNER JOIN TABLE_APPARTMENT_TYPES at ON at.app_type_id = a.apartment_type LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_TENANTS t ON a.building_id = t.building_id AND t.entity_id=1 AND t.status=true LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_COMMITTEE_DELEGATE cd ON
     a.building_id = cd.building_id AND cd.entity_id=1 AND cd.status=true
                WHERE a.building_id = 1 AND (t.entity_id=1 OR cd.entity_id=1)
                ORDER BY    a.apartment_num ASC
```

When I'm using PHP to read the result, I use:

```
while($ap = pg_fetch_array($_qry)){ 

}
```

and trying to read "e_name", which is part of the ROW(e.e_name), but I can't succeed.

Need your ideas ... please.

Comment: Do you get an error? what is it? Please elaborate on the 'can't succeed' statement :)

Comment: Did you output the SQL query and try it in the database directly? It may be unsuccessful and $_qry may not be a resource.

Answer (score 1):

use `pg_fetch_assoc`, to retrieve data in asoc-array; But my advice, - use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) to work with db in PHP.